# Distributing Contents for Linux like in Android & iOS?

Tags: linux, zip, execution

I'm currently designing a Linux-based system. Users of the system will be allowed to download contents, i.e. programs, from the Internet. The contents will be distributed in zip packages given special extension names, e.g. .cpk instead of .zip, and with zero compression.

I want to give users the same experience found in iOS and Android, in which contents are distributed in contained packages and run from there.

My question is that can I make my Linux system to run programs from inside the packages without unzipping them? If not, then is there another approach to what I'm after in Linux?

Please note that I don't want to extract contents into a temp folder and delete them after execution because that might take longtime, specially for large contents. That will also double the storage space requirements for running the contents.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[klik](http://code.google.com/p/klikclient/) (at least in the [klik2 CMG format](http://code.google.com/p/klikclient/wiki/CmgFormatOverview)) used an [zISO](http://freshmeat.net/projects/zisofs-tools/) image, which can be mounted by the kernel or by a FUSE client, rather than a zip.  You could use other filesystem types that are supported by the kernel or via FUSE.  Maybe [fuse-zip](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) is worth a shot?

You could also modify the loader to read directly out of the bundle.  For example, Android's Dalvik VM can load dex files directly from apk bundles, which are effectively zip files.  (Native code on Android, however, still needs to be unpacked first, and does take more time and space.  Modifying the native loader is… tricky.)

Comment: A squashfs file is another possibility.